# Cannot make new button of DatePickerDialog work

Tags: android, button, datepicker

I have a `AlertDialog` that contains a `EditText` but set to `android:focusable="false"` to bring up the date picker on tap.

And I set the datepicker as following:

```
final TextView date_from = (TextView)v_iew.findViewById(R.id.search_date_from_field);
//Cast EditText to TextView doesn't cause anyproblem to me so far, I don't think it's the problem
date_from.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Helper.datepicker(getActivity(), date_from);
            }
        });
```

And inside the `Helper` I make the `datepicker` method as following:

```
public static void datepicker(Context context, final TextView toBeDisplayed) {
    Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();

    final DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(context, new OnDateSetListener() { 
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {            

                year = selectedyear;
                month = selectedmonth;
                day = selectedday;

                toBeDisplayed.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
                        .append(month + 1).append("/").append(year).append(" "));

        }
    },mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date"); 

    //I added the Reset button below
    mDatePicker.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Reset",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.v("OLD STRING", toBeDisplayed.getText().toString());
            toBeDisplayed.setText("");
            Log.v("NEW STRING", toBeDisplayed.getText().toString());
            mDatePicker.dismiss();
        }
    });
    mDatePicker.show();
}
```

The date picking works, but the additional Rest button which I added doesn't. When I click Reset button, I only get the "OLD STRING" log with nothing else and it just closes the date picker dialog and return the selected date, not just to make it empty as I want.

But if I change `toBeDisplayed.setText("");` to `toBeDisplayed.append("blahblahblah");` I will get the "NEW STRING" log.

What is wrong with the `toBeDisplayed.setText("");`?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `I only get the "OLD STRING" log with nothing else` try to set default value in toBeDisplayed before `Helper.datepicker(getActivity(), date_from);` line then u will get default value onClick of `Reset`

Comment: Sadly set default value in the xml doesn't work. It still doesn't reach `toBeDisplayed.setText("");`

Comment: before `Helper.datepicker(getActivity(), date_from);` won't do it as well...